# How to set username and password using RESTEasy client builder?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a url which needs authentication (like a browser pop up appears asking username and password.)

[image]

Generally, we can use the following format to achieve this:

`http://username:password@url.com`

Using RESTEasy client builder

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 WebTarget target = client.target("http://url.com");
```

How to achieve it without having to construct the  `http://username:password@url.com` myself? I've seen if there are any methods which I could use to set it with no luck. Also I'm not sure how these credentials are passed, headers, cookies etc..

Comment: What type of authentication is it, Basic??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). If that's the case, you just need to set the `Authorization` header to `Basic base64encode(username:password)`.

For example:

```
String credentials = "username:password"
String base64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());
Response response = target.request()
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + base64encoded)....
```

The [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class I used is from Java 8. If you're not using Java 8, there are libraries that have Base64 support. Prior to Java 8, there's a `com.sun` internal `Base64` class, but it's advised **not** to use those.

If you just want to run a quick test (and don't have Java 8 or don't want to go looking for a lib), you can go to [this site](https://www.base64encode.org/) and just type in your `username:password` and encode it, then just copy and paste to your code.

For example:

```
base64encode(username:password) == dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```